# How to change grid row in a media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries, css-grid

I have an footer on my page that is assigned to grid-row 20, the final grid row of a 20x20 grid.  I want to reassign it to grid-row 15 for smaller media sizes.

Here is the css with the media queries:

```
#footer_x{
    grid-column: 6 / 15;
    grid-row: 20 / 20;
    font-family: robotoregular;
    font-size: 6px;
    color: rgb(100,100,100);
    padding-left: 15%;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in 150ms;
}

@media (min-width: 320px) {
  #footer_x { 
    font-size: calc( 0.0125vw + 3px );
    grid-row: 15 / 15; }
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {
  #footer_x { 
    font-size: 12px;
    grid-row: 20 / 20; }
}
```

Here is the css on the grid container:

```
.grid {
display: grid;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
grid-template-rows: repeat(20, 5%);
grid-template-columns: repeat(20, 5%);
}
```

While the font-size works in the media queries, the footer does not change position on a cell phone, and appears way too far down the page.  Nothing else in the code would affect this.

How can I change the grid-row for an element using media queries?

Comment: What is the CSS on your grid container?

Comment: It seems to work, can you provide a working example e.g. by using a snippet in your question?

Comment: I just updated my question with the css for the grid container.

Comment: It might be helpful to add the relevant HTML as well, to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue